# disable a control on Nintex forms based on rule for specific user ?

Tags: nintex-workflow

i want to disable a control on Nintex form for user in my active  directory 
 for example the name of user is  a.sedighi  and the name of domain is  elevator110 how can i do it? what kind of rule can i use to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The rule to disable a control based on current user is

> currentuser == "domainname\username"

Or create a group based to whom the control should be disabled.sect the control right click and under setting click on apperance tab and under disable select expression and add the below expression

Not(fn-IsMemberOfGroup(group name)